# Windows Workflow Foundation 4 (WF4) Persistence

Tags: windows, persistence, workflow-foundation-4

I've been working with Visual Studio 2010 Beta-2 to get some advanced learning on WF4.
Everything was going fine until today, when I un-installed Visual Studio 2010 Beta-2, and installed the Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate.  My code is complaining that it can’t find the System.Runtime.Persistence namespace that I am using, and also, the InstanceStore, and InstanceView types contained in that namespace.  Does anyone know if those types have been moved to a different namespace in the Release Candidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it in System.Runtime.DurableInstancing?

Protip:  remove the reference to System.Runtime and then compile.  The error message tells you what assembly to add.